# Semantic bug in rectangle object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class called `Rectangle` with methods for the rectangle's location, width and height, and I want to write a `__str__` method that will nicely print this information out. I've already done a similar thing with my `Point` class and it worked out just fine, but I think this time it's printing out the memory location of the methods instead of the information converted to a string.

This is my `Point` class, included here because it's needed to create a `Rectangle` object:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,initx,inity):
        self.x = initx
        self.y = inity

    def getx(self):
        return self.x

    def gety(self):
        return self.y

    def __str__(self):
        return 'x=' + str(self.x) + ', y=' + str(self.y)
```

This is `Rectangle`:

```
    class Rectangle:
        def __init__(self,lowerleft,awidth,aheight):
            self.location = lowerleft
            self.width = awidth
            self.height = aheight

        def get_width(self):
            return self.width

        def get_height(self):
            return self.height

        def get_location(self):
            return self.location

        def __str__(self):
            return 'Location: ' + str(self.location) + ', width: ' + str(self.get_width) + ', height: ' + str(self.get_height)
```

And this is the output for the line `print(my_rectangle)`:

```
Location: x=4, y=5, width: <bound method Rectangle.get_width of <__main__.Rectangle object at 0x1006c4190>>, height: <bound method Rectangle.get_height of <__main__.Rectangle object at 0x1006c4190>>
```

`print(my_rectangle.get_width())`, `print(my_rectangle.get_height())` and `print(my_rectangle.get_location())` worked exactly as expected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that it printed `bound method`... that's a tell-tale indicator that you've somehow referred to a method itself, but didn't actually call it. Often (like in your case) just a missing set of parenthesis `()`.

Comment: Yeah, that was it! It just needed parentheses after the method calls.

Comment: ...needed parenthesis to *call* the methods.`</pedantic>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must actually call your member methods:

```
return 'Location: ' + str(self.location) + ', width: ' + str(self.get_width()) + ', height: ' + str(self.get_height())
```

Nota bene the parentheses.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I was unsure of how variables and methods worked when called inside a class definition.

Comment: On a side note: All your getter functions are superfluous anyway.

Comment: Yeah, they aren't very useful and I changed the method to just use the values instead.